# Problemas con símbolo aritmético (C++)

Tags: c++, c, matemáticas, ecuacion-cuadratica, discriminante

No sé como sustituir un símbolo como este "±".

Este es el ejercicio que estoy haciendo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación dejo un trozo del código:

`resultado1 = (-b+sqrt(pow(b,2)-4*a*c))/(2*a);`

Comment: *El signo más menos (±) es un símbolo matemático que se emplea a menudo para indicar la precisión de una aproximación, o bien **para denotar abreviadamente un valor que puede ser tanto positivo como negativo**.*  [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%B1)

Answer (score 10):

Lo que estás tratando es resolver una **ecuación cuadrática** o de **segundo grado** y estas tienen **dos soluciones** por lo que puedes tener **2** **variables**, **x1** y **x2**:

```
float x1 = (-b + sqrt(pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
float x2 = (-b - sqrt(pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);
```

**x1** calcula la primera solución y **x2** la segunda solución.